# Add github repository to my composer project

Tags: github, composer-php

I like to create a new composer project. I will include code, that is not on packagist. It is a github repository. Concretely I like to include this release.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/4.0.0-alpha12

I expected with this `composer.json` to fetch the release 4.0.0-alpha12:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/my_joomla_website",
    "description": "Testing to install joomla with extensions via composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GNU",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "vendor",
            "email": "myemail"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "joomla/joomla-cms": "dev-4.0-dev#4.0.0-alpha12"
    }
}
```

But the command `comoser install` did not run to the end. This is my message

```
 composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]                                                    
  The process "git clone --mirror 'https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms.git' '/home/astrid/.composer/cache/vcs/htt  
  ps---github.com-joomla-joomla-cms.git/'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.                                     


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

In the end I have a vendor directory in my project folder. The content of the github repository is not there.

What do I have to do if I want to add code - hosted on github - to my Composer project?

Update
I just changed my `composer.json` to

```
{
    "name": "astrid/my_joomla_website",
    "description": "Testing to install joomla with extensions via composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GNU",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "vendor",
            "email": "myemail"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "joomla/joomla-cms",
                "version": "4.0.0-alpha12",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "git://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms.git",
                    "reference": "4.0-dev"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/4.0.0-alpha12/Joomla_4.0.0-alpha12-Alpha-Full_Package.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "joomla/joomla-cms": "dev-4.0-dev#4.0.0-alpha12"
    }
}
```

Now I get this error.

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package joomla/joomla-cms dev-4.0-dev#4.0.0-alpha12 exists as joomla/joomla-cms[4.0.0-alpha12] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

What am I doing wrong? I haven't assigned any dependencies or restrictions yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly causes your "rejected by your constraint" exception, but I'm guessing it's because you're using the `branch#ref` version requirement which the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) say isn't actively supported. I think you could rather just use the `4.0.0-alpha12` tag since a tag isn't tied to a branch.

To fix your first issue, change your repository type to `vcs` (or `github`). Composer will detect the the repository is a Github repository and will then use the Github API to fetch the correct version of the package. The [joomla-cms repository](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms) looks really big so it will probably take longer than the allowed 300 seconds to clone.

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms.git"
        }
    ]
```

For your second issue, set your version to `4.0.0-alpha12`:

```
    "require": {
        "joomla/joomla-cms": "4.0.0-alpha12"
    }
```

The `4.0.0-alpha12` version of joomla-cms requires a dev version of `joomla/application` (`joomla/application[2.0.x-dev]`) so you would have to set your package's [minimum stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) to `dev`:

```
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
```